NSURLErrorDomain: -1003 eventhough domain in App Transport Security Exceptions
I'm trying to perform a simple HTTPs POST request in my ios app using swift. However I get the error
nw_proxy_resolver_create_parsed_array [C1.1.1 proxy pac] Evaluation error: NSURLErrorDomain: -1003
I have already added the domain the request is being made to to the App Transport Security Exceptions.
For more detail. here is the code
        // ...
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/octet-stream", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpBody = try loginrequest.serializedBytes()
    
        let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
            throw NSError(domain: "NetworkRequestError", code: 0, userInfo: nil)
        }
        // ...

it gets executed when the user presses a certain button in the app.
Help is greatly appreciated.

-1003 is "cannot find host". You haven't shown your url, but you need to check it.  Also, the error message is from the proxy process. Are you running on a simulator?  The simulator will use any proxy server that is configured on your Mac, and it may be the proxy that is unable to find the host.

Thank you for your help @Paulw11!
The URL is guard let url = URL(string: "https://ankiweb.net/svc/account/login") else { return nil }
which does respond when asked a POST request as I do in my code.
Yes, I am running it through simulator but I have also tried on my iPhone, neither of them work.
My mac is not connected to a proxy
